# How do I add this sort of color field/effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, adobe-photoshop-elements

I want to do the overlay/filter effects below(note they are pretty subtle):

[image]

[image]

I've experimented with several blending options but I can't seem to find out how the make that overlay effect. A detailed response is appreciative. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a solid color with a gradient mask. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do this pretty easy.

1. Have a background image
2. Go to **Create new fill or adjustment layer** > **Solid Color**
3. Select a color
4. Click on the **Layer Mask** and take the **Brush tool**, choose **black** as the foreground color<sup>**(1)**</sup> and set it's hardness to 0 and it's opacity to 10-15%
   (or whatever makes you happy) and adjust the brush size.
5. Start painting where you want it to be see-through

[image]

<sup>**(1)**</sup> *When using a **Solid Color** you can change the color by double clicking on the **Layer thumbnail** and selecting a color. When clicking on the **Layer thumbnail mask** you can use two colors: black and white where full white means 100% opacity of the color you selected on the **Layer thumbnail** and full black means 100% Transparency of that same color.*

*So in our case, choosing a black brush with 15% opacity we are actually erasing 15% of the color's opacity, leaving it with only 85%.*

[image]

Result:
[image]

> It's better to use a brush instead of a gradient cause you have more
>   control over the result and you can give it different
>   shapes/sizes/opacity and by using a solid color you maintain full editing capabilities of everything and you can change the shape, the color, everything.